# Api versioning through header having same header name

Tags: java, spring-boot, header, postman, api-versioning

How to give multiple values to a controller for api versioning through header having same header name

```java
@PostMapping(value = URL.ADD, headers = {"X-API-VERSION=1.0", "X-API-VERSION=2.0"})
public int add(@RequestBody ProductVariant productVariant) {
    int result = productVariantBo.add(productVariant);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you format your question properly, someone is more likely to read it and try to answer your question.